# Protect app with fingerprint or app lock when screen time out

Tags: android

I can add fingerprint support to my android app. So at the very first time it is asking for the fingerprint authentication and unlock the app. But when the screen locks after first authentication, it never asks to authenticate again. How could i do that? I need to ask user the authentication whenever he is trying to access the app. Not only the very first time. code is below. It is simple code. if authenticated, load another fragment. I just want to lock the app when screen timeout.

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){

        fingerprintManager = (FingerprintManager) getSystemService(FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);
        keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);

        if (!fingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected()){
            //Fingerpring scanner not detected

        }else if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            //Permission not granted to use fingerprint scanner
        }else if(!keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure()){

            //Add lock in your phone locking
        }else if(!fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()){
            //Add at least one fingerprint
        }else{

            FingerPrintHelper fingerPrintHelper = new FingerPrintHelper(this);
            fingerPrintHelper.startAuth(fingerprintManager,null);
            startActivity(new Intent(FingerPrintActivity1.this, LoginActivity.class));
        }

    }
```

Comment: please add your code what you have tried

Comment: done. it is a simple code. just load an activity if authenticated. I want to ask authentication again if screen time out or lock.